# Reassign values in pandas df grouped by time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df below, where the columns are ordered by `Value`. So `-1` will always be first, followed by `0`, then `1`, then `2` etc.

**I want to reassign the `Value` integers based on the max number of counts for each integer.** Specifically, I want to leave `-1` as is. For all other numbers, I want `0` to be the most represented for each `Period`. Then make all other integers a `1`.

So if `0` has the most integers for a unique `Period`, then it's fine. If another integer has a higher count, then re-assign those values as 0 and swap the `0's` to `1`.

If we leave `-1` alone, `Period 1` has two `0's`, two `1's`, and two `2's`. So change the `2's` to a `1`.

`Period 2` has two `0's` and two `1's` so leave as is.

```
d = {'Item': ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "White", "Black", "Orange", "Yellow", "Brown", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "White", "Black", "Orange", "Yellow", "Brown"],
     'Value': [-1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     'Period': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['edge']=df.groupby('Period')['Value'].transform(lambda x:x.value_counts().diff().fillna(0).eq(0).all())
df['newval']=df.groupby('Period')['Value'].transform(lambda x:x.value_counts().idxmax())
m1=(df['newval'].ne(0) & df['newval'].eq(df['Value'])) & df['edge'].eq(False)
m2=(df['newval'].ne(0) & df['Value'].eq(0)) & df['edge'].eq(False)
df.loc[m1,'Value']=0
df.loc[m2,'Value']=1
df=df.drop(['newval','edge'],1)
```

df:

```
      Item  Value  Period
0      Red     -1       1
1     Blue     -1       1
2    Green      0       1
3    White      0       1
4    Black      1       1
5   Orange      1       1
6   Yellow      2       1
7    Brown      2       1
8      Red     -1       2
9     Blue     -1       2
10   Green     -1       2
11   White     -1       2
12   Black      0       2
13  Orange      0       2
14  Yellow      1       2
15   Brown      1       2
```

intended output:

```
      Item  Value  Period
0      Red     -1       1
1     Blue     -1       1
2    Green      0       1
3    White      0       1
4    Black      1       1
5   Orange      1       1
6   Yellow      1       1
7    Brown      1       1
8      Red     -1       2
9     Blue     -1       2
10   Green      0       2
11   White      0       2
12   Black      1       2
13  Orange      1       2
14  Yellow      1       2
15   Brown      1       2
```

Comment: Your description is quite confusing at the first glance , it would be helpful if you can add the expected output dataframe as well

Comment: It's outlined in intended output.

Comment: As in `Value` and `Period`?

Comment: In your example period 1 has two 0's (not three) and two 2s (not one) and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I'm conversing to @Anurag Dabas below. His functions work but there's one edge case that is outlined in my question. I'll re-adjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
df['edge']=df.groupby('Period')['Value'].transform(lambda x:x.value_counts().diff().fillna(0).eq(0).all())
df['newval']=df.groupby('Period')['Value'].transform(lambda x:x[x.ge(0)].value_counts().idxmax())
m1=(df['newval'].ne(0) & df['newval'].eq(df['Value'])) & df['edge'].eq(False)
m2=(df['newval'].ne(0) & df['Value'].eq(0)) & df['edge'].eq(False)
df.loc[m1,'Value']=0
df.loc[m2,'Value']=1
df=df.drop(['newval','edge'],1)
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your expected output

Comment: Yep, this is good but I need something more robust. For instance it may not be `1` that has the highest count and needs to be re-assigned. It could be a `2` or a `3`.

Comment: @Chopin updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: @Chopin change `eq()` to `isin()` in m1 and m2 if there are more numbers(if needed)

Comment: Say values go up to 5 (1,2,3,4,5), would `.isin([1,2,3,4,5])`work? It's changing everything to 0. Nothing is be re-assigned to 1.

Comment: @Chopin it's depend on which mask m1 or m2 you are using `isin()` if it's changing to 0 then you are probably using `isin()` in mask m2.....btw if values go upto 5 then what is the criteria you thought of changing 3,4,5 to 0 or 1?

Comment: So whatever integer has the highest count, re-assign those values as 0, then reassign all other values at 1.

Comment: @Chopin updated answer with this logic....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: @Chopin if -1 in is also included in your condition(whatever integer has the highest count, re-assign those values as 0, then reassign all other values at 1.) then you can remove `-1` from `isin()` in mask m2

Comment: This is really close @Anurag Dabas. I need the `0's` to be reassigned as `1's`. `Orange, Yellow, Brown` has be re-assigned to `0`. So `Green` and `White` should now be a `1`.

Comment: @Chopin so you want this logic **' I need the 0's to be reassigned as 1's. Orange, Yellow, Brown has be re-assigned to 0. So Green and White should now be a 1'** from the *beginning* of the question or *after* **'whatever integer has the highest count, re-assign those values as 0, then reassign all other values at 1.'** this logic?

Comment: So for each unique `Period`, find **highest count of integers**. If `0` has the most integers, then move on to next unique `Period`. If an integer other than `0` has a higher count, then re-assign those values as `0` and swap what where the `0's` to `1`.

Comment: @Chopin updated answer with this logic....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thanks. Just one final issue where even count occur between `ints`. It's changing `-1` to `0` and `0's` to `1's`

Comment: @Chopin since you updated df in your question so in that df max count is 2 for all values(1,-1,2,0) so in that 
scenario what you want to do?

Comment: Leave as is because 0 is still the highest. It's just equal highest.

Comment: @Chopin updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thanks Anurag. I'm sorry, there were more edge cases than I anticipated. If -1 has the greatest amount, it's disrupting the count. I'm hoping to leave -1 as is and deal with non-negative ints only

Comment: @Chopin  updated answer...kindly have a look :)